# Is "shaping" an adjective in "has been truly shaping for"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I'm writing this sentence:

> Five years at X has been truly shaping for my professional life and development.

Is "shaping" here used correctly as an adjective?

Comment: Very similar to the question today about [predicate adjectives formed from **past** participles](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603376/15299) instead of present.

Comment: Could you use *formative* so it's understood on the spot instead of standing out as too original by half? And, for a resume, *truly* adds a truly BS quality for me. Not meant as an insult.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with this is that, since "five years" is plural, you would need to use "have been shaping," not "has been shaping":

> Five years at X have been truly shaping for my professional life and development.

The second problem is that "have been shaping" would typically be interpreted as a single verb, namely a present perfect progressive one. Since "shape" in this sense is transitive, you would need to use a direct object, not the preposition "for":

> Five years at X have been truly shaping my professional life and development.

The third problem is the use of the progressive aspect; it suggests that the shaping is somehow incomplete, as if the five years have left you in an unfinished, half-shaped state. So you would need to change it to:

> Five years at X have truly shaped my professional life and development.

This version is correct.

Comment: (Yes, yes, I know CGEL wouldn't treat "have been shaping" as a *single* verb form, but I feel the need to defer to common usage.)

Comment: Can "five years" be considered singular, as in "five years is a long time"?